# Blender 2.81 32bit

Tags: versions

Will there be a version of blender `2.81` for 32bit windows as there was for `2.80`?
In my working environment we are currently unable to upgrade PCs.

Comment: Ask developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Blender 2.80](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.80/) was the last release for Windows 32-bit. This was announced on the [bf-committers mailing list](https://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2019-August/050124.html).

> Hi all,
>
> Blender 2.80 was the last release where we officially support 32 bit
>   Windows and Linux builds. For Blender 2.81 there will be only 64 bit
>   builds.
>
> We will continue to support it to the level that we do for example
>   ARM. That is we keep the Blender code working independent of the
>   processor architecture, particularly for Linux packages. But we don't
>   actively test them or release our own builds.
>
> Computers that meet the minimum graphics card requirements for 2.80
>   practically always have a CPU with 64 bit support as well. That means
>   the effective number of 32 bit users is very small by now.
>
> The associated task on developer.blender.org is here:
>   https://developer.blender.org/T67184
>
> Thanks, Brecht.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the [blender release archive](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.81/) so you would need to [build it yourself](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Windows), can't even find it on https://graphicall.org which would suggest that it's not a common thing to look for.

You'd probably find that it's only the Windows part that is 32-bit unless you are running some seriously old hardware ( more than 10 years old ), if that is the case then you're likely to have graphics card issues.  If it's a licensing issue, have you considered installing a 64-bit Linux instead, perhaps on a second disk?